# python remove element from nested list if it exists in another list +

Tags: python, list

lets say I have a list:

```
A = ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

and another one - nested:

```
B = [['x', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['y', 'c'], ['x', 'a', 'c', 'z']]
```

how can I remove 'z' from the last sublist in list B based on the knowledge that 'z' is in A and also every first element [0] of the sublist B is  in list A ?

so basically i need to detele all elements from such a nested list where element is in A and where it not stands in the first position of that nested list ?

I am trying this but get stacked:

```
for i in B:
    for j in i[1:]:
        if j in A:
            del j
```

but I am missing something.

Comment: Why are you skipping the 0th element in `i`?

Comment: @IanAuld: from the question: *and where it not stands in the first position of that nested list*

Comment: Can you add expected output? I don't quite get  *where it not stands in the first position of that nested list*, you seem to be ignoring all first elements

Comment: you can see it below in Martjin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension to update a list in-place:

```
for sublist in B:
    if sublist[0] in A:
        sublist[1:] = [v for v in sublist[1:] if v not in A]
```

`j` in your loop is only another reference to a value in a sublist. `del j` removes that one reference, but the list still contains that reference. You can remove values from the list with `del listobj[index]` or `listobj.pop(value)` (watch for subtleties in what those mean), but deleting from a list while iterating over it will result in items being skipped if you are not careful.

By assigning to a slice, you replace those elements in the list itself, in-place.

Note that you probably want to make `A` a *set*; membership testing is far faster when using a set:

```
Aset = set(A)

for sublist in B:
    if sublist[0] in Aset:
        sublist[1:] = [v for v in sublist[1:] if v not in Aset]
```

Demo:

```
>>> A = ['x', 'y', 'z']
>>> B = [['x', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['y', 'c'], ['x', 'a', 'c', 'z']]
>>> Aset = set(A)
>>> for sublist in B:
...     if sublist[0] in Aset:
...         sublist[1:] = [v for v in sublist[1:] if v not in Aset]
...
>>> B
[['x', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['y', 'c'], ['x', 'a', 'c']]
```

Comment: thank you, much appreciated. A was already a set but then I modified it again to list(A) because I thought playing with both list would be somehow easy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> [sub[:1]+[i for i in sub[1:] if not(sub[0] in A and i in A)] for sub in B]
[['x', 'a', 'b', 'c'], ['y', 'c'], ['x', 'a', 'c']]
```

Here you'll preserve the items from sublists (from second item to end) that doesn't met your conditions for deleting.

Comment: Yeah, you could, but here I wouldn't. `not (sub[0] in A and i in A)` is not exactly rolling of the tongue.

Comment: @MartijnPieter Maybe, but sometimes it's cool to use double negative elimination in scripts :-).